# I have issues implementing a 'bomberman explosion' into my game C# Monogame

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to make a bomberman explosion in my bomberman clone. I have all the necessary classes implemented in the game, such as Player, Tilemap, Bomb, Grass, Stone etc. However, I struggle to stop / halt the explosion after it hits a block. By this I mean that the explosion (sometimes) continues even after it hits a collidable Tile (Stone, Crate, etc).

**What have I done?**

As I stated above, I have not done a recursive explosion. Instead, I took another approach.

I  made two classes, a Fire class and an Explosion class. The Fire class is an explosion on **one** specific tile. So if I set a Fire object at (1,1) in the Tilemap grid. It will only explode in that specific tile. The fire class checks for collision in it's Update() function. If it finds a collision it sets HasHitWall to true.

The Explosion class is simple, but it is the class that I can't get to work properly. The Explosion class contains a List of **Fire** instances. These Fire instances are set in the constructor:

```cs
fires = new List<Fire>();
int counter = 1;

for (int x = 0; x < length * 4; x+=4) {
    fires.Add(new Fire(position + new Vector2(-Tile.tileSize.X * counter * InGameScreen.scale,0)));   //Left;
    fires.Add(new Fire(position + new Vector2(Tile.tileSize.X * counter * InGameScreen.scale, 0)));   //Right;
    fires.Add(new Fire(position + new Vector2(0, -Tile.tileSize.Y * counter * InGameScreen.scale)));   //Up;
    fires.Add(new Fire(position + new Vector2(0,Tile.tileSize.Y * counter * InGameScreen.scale)));   //Down;

    counter++;
}
```

In the for loop, there are four different fires, all going in different directions. I have commented which direction they are heading.

The first Fire object initialized in the constructor is the fire going in the left direction. This Fire object has the index 0 as it is put first in the List. When the next Fire object heading left is added, it will have index 4. The one after that will have index 8 and so on.

I see a pattern that there is an index difference of four between every fire in one direction. To clarify, the first Fire going left has index 0, the next Fire object going left will have index 4 and so on.

I took this concept into the Update() function where I try to remove the all the Fire objects in one direction **after** a Fire has collided with a Tile.

```cs
for (int x = 0; x < fires.Count; x++) {
    fires[x].Update(gameTime);

    if (fires[x].HasHitWall == true) {
        for (int i = x; i < fires.Count; i += 4) {
            fires.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

However this does not work, it removes Fire objects all over the place. I need help figuring out how to solve this issue. **How can I remove all the Fires in one direction after a specific Fire has collided with a Tile?**

That might be a vague and difficult question to understand, however, I don't know how to explain it in another way.

Image of it happening:

[image: Pictue of the issue]

**What can the issue be?**

I thought the issue could be that I use a List. However, I tried this with an array and it didn't work either. The indexes has to be where they are. If index 4 is removed, then index 5 **can't** be allowed to become index 4. It has to stay as index 5.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are bothering with list indices? Instead of removing blocked fires, I would not create them in the first place. Handle each direction separately.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Isn't that bad code? How am I supposed to "not create them in the first place"? Do you mean that I should check if the position I want to place it in is colliding with a Tile? If so not create it?

Comment: You cannot remove items that you are iterating over in a for-loop. If you have three items and remove the first one, the second will become the first thereby being skipped, the third will become the second and accessing the third will lead to index out of bounds.

Comment: @Palle Due So I should do i— as well?

Comment: There are two ways to do it: 1) In a while loop where you don't increase the counter after removal or 2) running through the list once getting the indices to remove and then remove them in another loop. But the best choice is the one above: Don't create the fire, if you don't need it. And that's definitely not bad programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to state that I solved this issue thanks to @PallarDue & @NicoSchertler.

I had to reorganize my code and play around a bit, but I finally got it working. I will try to sum it up.

The idea is simple, I have an if statement that checks if the direction of fires it belongs to has previously collided. Lets say that index 4 in my fires array collides with a crate. Then I don't want any more fires to be created in that specific direction.

Afterwards I make a Fire object and I check if that Fire object's hitbox collides with any of the colliders hitboxes using *IsFireColliding(Fire fire)*. This method loops through all the collidables and returns true or false depending if any collision is detected.

If IsFireColliding returns false, then I add the fire to my fires List.

If it returns true, then I add the object to my list and set the direction bool (directionContinue[x]) equal to false. Setting the bool to false hinders any more fires to be created in that direction.

Here is the code to the class that does this:

```
    private void AddFire(Vector2 offset, int directionContinueIndex) {

    if (directionContinue[directionContinueIndex])
    {
        Fire fire = new Fire(position + offset);   

        if (!IsFireColliding(fire))
        {
            fires.Add(fire);
        }
        else if (IsFireColliding(fire) && directionContinue[directionContinueIndex] == true)
        {
            fires.Add(fire);
            directionContinue[directionContinueIndex] = false;

        }

    }

}
```

Here is the code to the IsFireColliding method that loops through and checks collsion:

```
    private bool IsFireColliding(Fire fire) {
   
    foreach (ICollidable c in InGameScreen.collidables) {

        if (fire.hitboxRectangle.Intersects(c.hitboxRectangle))
        {
            return true;
        }
      
            
    }
 
    return false;
}
```

To make this work in all directions I have to do the AddFire() method four times (four different directions). I also want to mention that I use a bool array with a length of four to keep track of which directions that has collided.

```
    public Explosion(Vector2 position, int length) : base(position) {
    
    fires = new List<Fire>();
    

    //Test code
    for (int x = 0; x < length * 4; x+=4) { //Check if you need to create a fire

        AddFire(new Vector2(-Tile.tileSize.X * counter * InGameScreen.scale, 0), 0);

        AddFire(new Vector2(Tile.tileSize.X * counter * InGameScreen.scale, 0), 1);

        AddFire(new Vector2(0, -Tile.tileSize.Y * counter * InGameScreen.scale), 2);

        AddFire(new Vector2(0, Tile.tileSize.Y * counter * InGameScreen.scale), 3);

        counter++;
    }


}
```

I hope this helped someone who is in the same boat as me!